# MySQL Syntax Error - ERROR 1064 because of a close bracket

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a mysql table and am getting the following error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 19

here is the create table script:

```
CREATE TABLE User(
userID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (userID),
username char(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
lastName char(30) NOT NULL,
firstName char(30) NOT NULL,
birthDay int NOT NULL CHECK(birthDay BETWEEN 1 AND 31),
birthMonth int NOT NULL CHECK(birthMonth BETWEEN 1 AND 13),
birthYear int NOT NULL CHECK(birthYear > 1900),
password char(30) NOT NULL,
geschlecht char(30) NOT NULL,
profilPicURL char(255) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT fk_lives_in
FOREIGN KEY (lives_in)
REFERENCES  Location(LocationID),
CONSTRAINT fk_comes_from
FOREIGN KEY (comes_from)
REFERENCES  Location(LocationID),
);
```

i appreciate any help,
thanks!

Comment: Last comma is extra. Count to line 19 and figure it out next time.

Comment: thank you!! very silly mistake

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE User(
userID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT Primary Key,
username char(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
lastName char(30) NOT NULL,
firstName char(30) NOT NULL,
birthDay int NOT NULL CHECK(birthDay BETWEEN 1 AND 31),
birthMonth int NOT NULL CHECK(birthMonth BETWEEN 1 AND 13),
birthYear int NOT NULL CHECK(birthYear > 1900),
password char(30) NOT NULL,
geschlecht char(30) NOT NULL,
profilPicURL char(255) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT fk_lives_in
FOREIGN KEY (lives_in)
REFERENCES  Location(LocationID),
CONSTRAINT fk_comes_from
FOREIGN KEY (comes_from)
REFERENCES  Location(LocationID)
);
```

Try it now